# How to initialize Firebase PWA app when offline?

Tags: angular, firebase, progressive-web-apps, angularfire2, angularfire2-offline

I am having issues when lunching my PWA app in offline mode. When I do that I get

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error). ; Zone: <root> ; Task: HTMLScriptElement.addEventListener:error ; Value: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error).
```

When I start the app when online and then turn offline, things goes well, cache and sync works good. However if I refresh the page then things go blank. Any idea how to fix it?

I am using Angular 12 and AngularFire.

Comment: Try to update to latest version of firebase package.